# Variable conditional output type for Arrays

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I know that Typescript will automatically infer if the output is an array or not, but I'm trying to figure out how to set it explicitly using conditional type.

I've tried something like the below, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
function test<T>(...args:any[]): T extends any[] ? any[] : any {

    // If there is only 1 arg, return a string
    if(args.length === 1)
        return 1;

    // If there is more than 1 args, return an array
    else
        return [1,2,3]
}
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error it gives (2322) is the same as the error you get with code like this:

```js
function example<T>(x: number | string): T {
    if (typeof x === "number") {
        return x * 2;
    }
    return x + x;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgHgBUA+AClQC5EwRMAjZAJ0QB9EBnKJmMAcwCU1IogDeAWABQiGYhjBEZKAE9syOAtSIAvLsQAiWg2b6BYqbMuImyKCCZItAKkQAmANwXZAXy8ybdg6IWgDUwZ6SvpJAA)

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'number'. (2322)

What that's saying is that I can write code like this:

```js
example<object>(42);
```

...and then `T` is `object`, but neither `number` nor `string` is assignable to `object`.

The same applies to your `test` function.

I think you were just experimenting with conditional types, but just for completeness, as you say the TypeScript compiler could infer those return values, but it would infer a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types), in that specific case `1 | number[]`. If you wanted to tell TypeScript that `test` with one argument returns `number` and `test` with more than one argument returns `number[]`, you can do that with a function overload:

```js
function test(x: any): number;
function test(x: any, y: any, ...more: any[]): number[];
function test(...args:any[]): number | number[] {

    // If there is only 1 arg, return a string
    if(args.length === 1)
        return 1;

    // If there is more than 1 args, return an array
    else
        return [1,2,3]
}

const x = test(1);          // type of `x` is `number`
const y = test(1, 2, 3);    // type of `y` is `number[]`
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgB4C5ECGYAngJT5ggC2ARigE4DcAsAFCiSwLLpZ6EkANImL4ixYQDppVOPRRiSAbQC65RJVoNVLduGjwkqDJmmSC9AOZpc41es116iAD4bqT1YgDebNogDEAHogxABJYGQACwYURBg0RAQAG2JEAEZCK2F5KBB6JAJEDHoYMEt-QJhgTAtrSWSUcqgoxABeDozSSsDA3PykdN0e4NCI6Nj4xNl5aKIMrOsclDyCgSz6AmIRlGS0FBHe-rWldMEAJkEAZhU2AF8-VggEDERsdp4TdNJGXr-R5DEAAOcTgkQABthwVNEODHAxwWxnmBXmk2p8sGdEJdEFcfr0QoCQUkIcRoQlYfD6KpEawgA)